How to load images in async to the javascript execution (Splide)? To fix LCP issue only on Mobile
I am having a carousel (splide) of images, at the top of my page.
And I see that I am having a very poor LCP score because of that, only on Mobile while having high score on Desktop. The issue seems to be the Load Delay section which mean:
Time to first byte (TTFB) - The time from when the user initiates loading the page until when the browser receives the first byte of the HTML document response. Learn more about TTFB.
Load delay - The delta between TTFB and when the browser starts loading the LCP resource.
One thing that I suspect is that first the Javascript to initialize and render the carousel is being executed and only then it starts to download the images.
Is there a way to download them in async matter? Using Next 12.3.4
Also if there's any other method to deal with the LCP issue I am facing I will be glad to try.

In Next.js, the next/image component has some configurations to optimise image loading:
Priority Loading:
To prioritize the loading of specific images, you can use the priority property within the next/image component. This allows you to indicate which images are critical and should load first, enhancing performance:
eg:
{images.map((image, index) => (
  <SplideSlide key={index}>
    <Image
      src={image.src}
      alt={image.alt}
      layout="responsive"
      width={700}
      height={475}
      priority={index === 0} // Set priority for the first image
    />
  </SplideSlide>
))}

Otherwise you can use loading = "lazy" to prevent initial load image to reduce LCP score
eg :
 <Image
  src="/path/to/image.jpg"
  alt="Description of the image"
  width={500}
  height={300}
  loading="lazy" // Enable lazy loading
/>


I switch to using regular  tag because Next.js doesn't support srcSet, and I often use images that has better CDN than mine so it's better for me to not optimize them on my own. And I couldn't find a way to use unoptimized image + srcSet
